# Bootstrap 3 Carousel indicators and controls not working? Triple checked everything

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Why aren't the carousel-indicators or carousel-controls working here...

```
<div id="#myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

   <div class="item active" id="slide1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Text...p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-success" href="#" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item" id="slide2">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Factors Suite</h2>
          <p>Enjoy a luxury stay in the Factors Suite which features furniture crafted from reclaimed timber and works by contemporary Scottish artists.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-info" href="#" role="button">View Gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- end carousel-inner -->

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>

</div><!-- end carousel -->
```

At the foot of my page I have:

```
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/docs.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried using bootstrap.js instead - that doesn't work.  Driving me mad this because I have the Carousel example from the Bookstrap 3 website, which works when I test it, and it is identical!

This is all live at the following URL:
http://www.cairnsmorecottages.co.uk/rickwood/index.php

Hoping some bright spark will spot the glaring mistake because there clearly is one here (my conception?)!  Thank you.

NJ

Comment: Correct your `dropdown.js`. in `http://www.cairnsmorecottages.co.uk/rickwood/js/dropdown.js`

Comment: I'm getting a net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from your server. Is your server properly up?

Comment: Khay, I removed the dropdown.js reference - I was led to believe (Bootstrap documentation) that you needed to include that to have nav-pills with dropdowns - and my dropdowns are working again.  That didn't fix the carousel though.  Exoddus has sussed it but the left control still isn't working.  Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why ID from DIV `<div id="#myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">` include '#' character?

Remove '#' from id

**EDITED AFTER COMMENTS:**

Review your html div tags. You can compare your html with this:

https://jsfiddle.net/35esebmp/

Comment: Thank you!  The left chevron control still isn't working though?

Comment: EDIT: Seems to be a problem with the indicators and caption overlaying the control. Is that a z-index problem?

Answer (score 0):

check this solution, work fine for me

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
          $(".carousel-indicators").click(function(){ 
            $(".carousel").carousel('prev');
          })
          $(".left").click(function(){ 
            $(".carousel").carousel('prev');
          })
          $(".right").click(function(){ 
            $(".carousel").carousel('next');
          })
        });
```